# Using Laravel 4 for a subproject of a larger existing project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am starting a small project that I think might be well suited for Laravel 4. However, the project would have to coexist with a much larger existing legacy project, one that has its own bootstrapping system and routing (via htaccess). Is there a good way to have Laravel 4 coexist with an existing project in this way?

The way you normally start  a Laravel 4 project basically takes over the entire project directory. That wouldn't be suitable for our current legacy project, which has many of the php scripts right in the public_html directory. Perhaps the entire Laravel project could be installed in a subdirectory of the main project, but that seems like a fairly messy solution. Is there a better way?

Comment: You answered your own question.....basically you would put the public directory inside public_html, and the rest of your laravel app outside......but getting it to play nice with the htaccess file you currently use might be tricky, unless these are just gonna run seperately off the same database....then its just a matter of giving both a different domain/pointer, so that when you visit one, it triggers the index.php and htaccess folder inside your laravel folder....I think that came out how I meant it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Laravel 4 components can be used without installing or using the full Laravel 4 framework - it's really flexible and pieces can be swapped out.

I would use Namespaced Controllers and Models, map your legacy code to them and slowly migrate over as alot of Laravel 4 can be used individually in external projects.

Eventually you can move over the routing to the Laravel 4 or any other Router you choose.

I've used the Database Layer in a Codeigniter project without any problems.

The only thing you need to be careful of is the PHP version as it relies on mcrypt, but if your're not using any of the password features I think you'll be okay.

Comment: Maybe my initial question wasn't clear: I want to use the whole stack of Laravel for the sub-project, not just a few of the components, I just don't want it to affect my main project.

Comment: If you install it in a sub directory and it's setup properly you shouldn't have any problems. The only issue then to be aware of is that you need PHP >= 5.3.7 and MCrypt PHP Extension. Sorry meant to add that you might be able to install it outside any sub directories as long as the installed directory is accesible. In any event without more details it's hard to say.